# Cannot save NSDictionary Deserialized from Json returned from .Net web service to Plist

Tags: objective-c, json, plist

I have a .net webservice which returns a Json data in this format:

```
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataPlist options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&errorJson];

[
{
    "MEMBERID": "xxx",
    "PREFIXINFORMAL": "Mr.",
    "FIRSTNAME": "xxx",
    "MIDDLENAME": "xxxx",
    "LASTNAME": "xxxx",
    "SUFFIX": xxxx
}
```

]

My code to save this NSDictionary to plist:

```
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"boardMemberInfo.plist"];
        NSDictionary *test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
        for(NSDictionary *item in json) {
            BOOL success = [item writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
            if(success) {
                NSLog(@"Success Saving New plist");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failure Saving New plist");
            }
        }
```

Neither [item writeToFile...] nor [json writeToFile...] works. However, simple [test writeToFile...] works. What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing you could do is to decompose your saving process and use NSError to understand what the problem is:

```
    for(NSDictionary *item in json) {
        NSError *error;
        NSData *serializedData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:item format:… options:… error:&error];
        if (!serializedData) { NSLog(@"Can't serialize data: %@", error); continue; }
        if (![serializedData writeToFile:path options:… error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't write to %@: %@", path, error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Success Saving New plist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is a null value returned from the query so the writeToFile failed. I use a decode() sql function to not return any null. It works now.